# Access to option page by role/capability

Tags: user-roles, options

So i've been googling around and i'm trying to figure out a plain simple solution to my problem. I've tried several things but they are simply not working. I just got into WordPress and i have to edit some permissions. I want to give the Editor rank access to ONE specific plugin. I've determined that this is the piece of code that returns a false or true statement ( Are you an admin? ).

The editor should have sufficient rights to work in the settings tab of this plugin. This is the piece of code. I'm not asking for straight answers, i just need some advice.

```
if (is_admin() ){
add_action('admin_menu', 'rooster_admin_menu');
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'rst_add_registration');
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'rst_cancel_registration');
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'rst_delete_event');
function rooster_admin_menu(){
    add_options_page('Rooster', 'Rooster', 'administrator', 'rooster', 'rooster_html_page');
}
```

Comment: so what is your Question basically. What do you want???

Comment: I want to give the editor permission to get access to Options->Plugin. (the options/settings tab and then the plugin section.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cheating, are we? Editor role not saving settings page for custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/268111/cheating-are-we-editor-role-not-saving-settings-page-for-custom-post-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this via the [`option_page_capability_{$option_page}`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/option_page_capability_%7B%24option_page%7D) hook - like:

```
function wpse151616_grant_access_to_options_page_for editors() {
    return 'edit_posts';
}
add_filter( 'option_page_capability_rooster', 
            'wpse151616_grant_access_to_options_page_for editors' );
```

For possible return values take a look at [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). The variable part - `{$option_page}` - of the hook name is substituted by the menu slug - `$menu_slug` - value of your [`add_options_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page) call.

Comment: My pleasure, don't forget to tick the answer, if it solved your problem. @user54667

Comment: I will not! Don't worry :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research and I've found another way to fix this issue. I assigned permissions to editors using the function :)

```
  if ( is_admin() )  
{  
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_plugin_for_editors' );  
}  

function add_plugin_for_editors()   
{  
    if (!current_user_can( 'manage_options' ))  
    {  
        add_menu_page('Rooster', 'Rooster', 'editor', 'rooster', 'rooster_html_page');  
    }  
}
```

Comment: But with this they only can *access* the page. They still can't *save* the form.